# How do I get TP-Link Archer T1U USB wireless dongle working?

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, usb, mediatek

I'm brand-new to the world of Ubuntu, and completely clueless. I am trying to install a TP-Link Archer T1U USB wireless adapter, but I can't find an appropriate driver. The TP-Link website only states driver support up to kernel 3.16. I tried following their instructions anyway, but of course it didn't work.

My `lsusb` report:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c048 Logitech, Inc. G9 Laser Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 2357:0105
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And no proprietary or additional drivers show up under "Software & Updates".

Help!

Comment: // , I tried a search for the same thing, to no avail: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=driver+%222357%3A0105%22&t=canonical&ia=web

Comment: did you also post here http://wyldeplayground.net/need-tp-link-t1u-driver-for-ubuntu-16-04/ ?

Comment: Nope, I didn't post on Wylde Playground.

Comment: Looks like this guy got it to work on his Pi, but are Ubuntu and Raspbian similar enough, or two totally different animals?

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=44044&p=872329

Comment: @twitcher: The crucial thing appears to be the Linux kernel version. The kernel in the linked forum post is v4.1 while Ubuntu 16.04 comes with kernel v4.4.

Answer (score 5):

I got this wireless adapter working on Ubuntu with kernel 4.4.

I added a driver to my PPA. It can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mt7610u-dkms
```

Comment: All I get is `E: Unable to locate package mt7610u-dkms`

Comment: This works great on Ubuntu 16.04. Doesn't work on Linux Mint 18.1 sadly. I am new to Linux so cannot add much to why it doesn't work on mint.

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty) and got this error: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

Comment: This PPA does not support `zesty`.

Comment: Further to my last comment: I just tried this again with Ubuntu 16, not 15, and it seems to work!

Comment: Anyone found a solution for Ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: @Samaursa Well, this no longer works with Ubuntu 16.04 as well, as the current kernel is `4.10.0-28-generic` and fails with: `error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)`

Comment: Obviously the dkms driver doesn't build with the 4.10 kernel. It needs patching.

Comment: Tried to install 4.4 kernel for Ubuntu 17.04, but for some reason also got this: `error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode`. @Pilot6 How hard would it be to patch the code, what do you think?

Comment: It is not hard to patch the driver for 4.10, but I don't plan to do it. I don't have this hardware and won't support it with new kernels. I was asked to pack the driver to a PPA with dkms.conf for the 4.4 kernel. I did it. Period.

Comment: Thanks for info. Those drivers seem to work with kernel 4.10: https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u
I can see the T1U device and scan Wifi networks, however experiencing some issues with Network Manager (device not managed).

Comment: Device is not managed if you changed something in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated here

http://forum.tp-link.com/showthread.php?84046-AC-450-Wireless-Nano-USB-Adapter-Archer-T1U-Linux-drivers

the official driver is not compiling anymore.

One workaround (using kernel 4.4.0-45-generic here atm) is to replace all occurrences of "-Wall" with "-Wno-unused-variable -Wno-error=date-time" in MODULE/os/linux/config.mk

After "make install" succeeded, reinsert the stick and check with "iwconfig" if device "ra0" (or similar) shows up.