# TP-Link Archer T1U Ubuntu 16.04 driver

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

I recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu. My laptop has an internal wifi card, but since its 2.4Ghz, I use an external 5Ghz nano usb. My external wifi card is TP-Link "Archer T1U".

The driver on the official website is for Linux (Kernel version 2.6~3.16), however I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Kernel version 4.4.0-53-generic)

(http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/Archer-T1U.html#Driver)

After searching for a while, I found out that by changing some of the variables before the driver installation, I can actually install the driver.

(https://askubuntu.com/a/842655)

Eventually, I was able to install the wifi card. I searched for available networks from the terminal and joined my 5Ghz network, and finally the indicator light started flashing on the wifi card.

So, here is the problem:

1) I have to use the terminal and ~ 5 commands to connect to any 5Ghz network because I am not able to use the wifi card from the ubuntu Network Connection Tool which is on the top right side of screen

2) After connecting to the 5Ghz network I did a Speedtest, and I only got 50 Mbps where as on Windows I am able to get 100-150 Mbps, which made me suspicious that the Ubuntu is using the wlo1 connection and not ra0 connection (external wifi card).

3) To further investigate this, I disconnected from 2.4Ghz network (internal wifi card) and the wifi bars on the top right side of screen went off. Although the indicator lights on the external wifi card were flashing, I cannot browse the internet.

Is there any way I can actually use the external wifi card instead of it just being recognised by Ubuntu and a flashing indicator light?

One thing to add is that, when I do `lsub`, i get the following result:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c0e Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2357:0105  
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 045e:0800 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

out of which, `Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2357:0105` is the external wifi card.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsusb`. I suspect you will have better luck if you blacklist the internal; let's identify it: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555: Thank you so much. I have edited the original question.


I identified the internal wifi card as:
`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
 DeviceName: Intel WLAN Intel Jackson Peak 1 802.11bgn 2x2 + BT combo Half M
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4062]`

Comment: Are you quite certain that the internal won't do 5 Ghz? With the USB *de*tached, please run: `sudo iwlist channel` and look for 5 Ghz. Perhaps you need a firmware upgrade.

Comment: The internal wifi card (wlo1) has 11 channels in total; with available frequencies ranging from 2.412 to 2.62. I am not sure how I can upgrade the firmware though.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you blacklist the driver for the internal device as it probably conflicts with the USB. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist iwlwifi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r iwlwifi
exit
```

Is the USB working better now?

It may take a reboot.